# How to apply a CSS class on hover to dynamically generated submit buttons?

Tags: html, css, hover, mousehover

I have the following piece of HTML/CSS code which is used to display pages based on the number of rows retrieved from a database.

```css
.paginate {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    padding:3px;
    margin:3px;
}

.disableCurrentPage {
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#999;color:#FFF; 
    border:1px solid #999;
    text-decoration:none;color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.paging {
    cursor: pointer; 
    background-color: transparent;border:1px solid #999;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#9CC;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div class='paginate'>
    <input type="submit" name="btnFirst" value="First" 
           class="disableCurrentPage" disabled="disabled"/>
    <input type="submit" name="btnPrev" value="Previous" class="paging"/>
        
    <input type="submit" name="btnPage" value="1"
           class="disableCurrentPage" disabled="disabled"/>
    <input type="submit" name="btnPage" value="2" class="paging"/>
    <input type="submit" name="btnPage" value="3" class="paging"/>
    <input type="submit" name="btnPage" value="4" class="paging"/>
    <input type="submit" name="btnPage" value="5" class="paging"/>
    <input type="submit" name="btnPage" value="6" class="paging"/>
    <input type="submit" name="btnPage" value="7" class="paging"/>
    <input type="submit" name="btnPage" value="8" class="paging"/>
    <input type="submit" name="btnPage" value="9" class="paging"/>
    <input type="submit" name="btnPage" value="10" class="paging"/>
        
    <input type="submit" name="btnNext" value="Next" class="paging"/>
    <input type="submit" name="btnLast" value="Last" class="paging"/>
</div>
```

Upto this there is no question. I want to apply the CSS class something like the following to all of those buttons on mouse hover.

```css
.button:hover {
    border:1px solid #999;
    color:#000;
}
```

Those buttons with the name attribute `btnPage` are generated **dynamically** in a loop. Therefore, I think it is inconvenient to apply the preceding CSS class based on the `id` attribute.

So, how can this class be applied to those buttons on hover?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Add the below code

```css
input[type="submit"]:hover {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    color: #000;
}
```

If you need only for these button then you can add id name

```css
#paginate input[type="submit"]:hover {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    color: #000;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kA2qM/3/)**

Comment: this will target all the inputs, not the ones with btnPage name attribute as Tiny asked.

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos He is asking for all buttons (I want to apply the CSS class something like the following to all of those buttons on mouse hover.). Those buttons with the name attribute btnPage are generated dynamically so it is not a good idea to assign the class name coz you cant give class name for dynamically generated buttons. This is what he is saying

Comment: Well his English is not perfect obviously.. I think he should clarify.  If he wants all inputs to have some styling then #paginate input {} will do it - but I don't understand why he had to mention the name btnPage attribute part..

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos :) his questions is clear. The reason why he has mentioned the btnPage attribute is to say its not possible to style the button with class name since it is dynamically generated.

Comment: but it is. CSS will be applied to all elements, even if they're loaded with an Asynchronous call or whatever. That's the thing.

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos He has no idea about styling the button with direct tags like how we both are doing. That is why he has mentioned it I guess

Comment: I think, in the second case, `#` should be replaced by `.` like - `.paginate input[type="submit"]:hover{border: 1px solid #999;color:#000;}`.

Answer (score 5):

The most **efficient** selector you can use is an [attribute selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/attributeselector).

```
 input[name="btnPage"]:hover {/*your css here*/}
```

Here's a **live demo**: **http://tinkerbin.com/3G6B93Cb**

Comment: This doesn't work when you add the custom style http://tinkerbin.com/noZjmZkA    The result showing in your page is default hover style of button

Comment: You changed my example, that's not what I pasted.

Comment: I changed to show you the effect. It should work with that style. In your demo if you remove the css also it gives the same result

Comment: I changed the url. The problem is that input elements should not be changed with CSS rules.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Extend your `.paging` class definition:

   ```css
   .paging:hover {
       border:1px solid #999;
       color:#000;
   }
   ```
2. Use the DOM hierarchy to apply the CSS style:

   ```css
   div.paginate input:hover {
       border:1px solid #999;
       color:#000;
   }
   ```