# CSS Changing Attribute of Specific Button

Tags: css, button

I have a button with the button class **button.ttfm2** but I want to change **button[type="submit"]:hover** this specific button:

At the moment my current code is:

```
.ttfm2 button[type="submit"]:hover {
background-color: #28AE47 !important;
}
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Check this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243656/how-to-apply-a-css-class-on-hover-to-dynamically-generated-submit-buttons

Comment: General advice: Use helper classes on the submit button so that you don't need to use the attribute selector. Also, use the specificity of your selectors to control the order of the cascade to avoid having to use !important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right code would be:

```
button[type="submit"].ttfm2:hover {
   background-color: #28AE47; /* avoid using !important */
}
```

You were trying to select the button of type submit inside ttfm2 element using descendant selector but you need to use the multiple selector i.e. the button that has a class `ttfm2`

**Sample Output:**

```css
button[type="submit"].ttfm2 {
  transition: all ease 2s;
}
button[type="submit"].ttfm2:hover {
  background-color: #28AE47;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="ttfm2">Test</button>
<button class="ttfm2">This will not work</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

a selector:

```
button[type="submit"].ttfm2:hover {
   background-color: #28AE47 !important;
}
```